# C++ passing array of pointers to function

Tags: c++, pointers

I have problem with passing array of pointers to a function.

Class CTree01 is child of CDecorationObj.
When I use for loop, it's working fine.

Here's my code:

```
CTree01 *trees01;
int numTree01 = ...;

trees01 = new CTree01[numTree01];

//main loop
for(int i=0;i<numTree01;i++)
    {
        {
            //Everything is working okay here, renders all trees
            glPushMatrix();
            trees01[i].DrawOnTerrain(camera);
            glPopMatrix();
        }
    }
```

but since i replaced for with a function, it's not working anymore:

```
void DrawDecorationType(CDecorationObj* objs, int number, CCamera *camera)
{
    int x,z;
    for(int i=0;i<number;i++)
    {
        {
            glPushMatrix();
            objs[i].DrawOnTerrain(camera);
            glPopMatrix();
        }
    }
}

//main loop
DrawDecoration(trees01, numTree01, camera);
```

When I do in that function:

```
objs[0].DrawOnTerrain(camera);
```

it works, and it crashes only when I render objects with index > 0 so I think it must be problem with parameter passed to the function.

Comment: You are treating your objs[]-Array with type `CDecorationObj` which certainly has a different length than `CTree01` Let's say `CDecorationObj` is 10 Byte in size, and `CTree01` is 20, when you are accessing `objs[1]` you are just half-way into the next tree object (memory-wise) and you get a wrong address for `this ` when calling `DrawOnTerrain`. Try using pointers to your internal elements, (e.g. `CTree**` and `CDecorationObj**`)

Comment: you shouldn't be `new`ing and `delete`ing just because, and you especially shouldn't be using raw pointers as arrays. Google `std::vector`.

Comment: I replaced "CDecorationObj* objs" with "CDecorationObj** objs" but now I got error "cannot convert parameter 1 from 'D_CTree02 **' to 'CDecorationObj **'"

Comment: @Barcio77 Ok, but just that is not enough^^ You'll have to also allocate each single `CTree` with `new` - I hope you did this also. Taking the above comment from our physically enhanced pastry friend into account, you should consider using `std::vector<CDecorationObject*>`. Also see the answer from R Sahu below, he explains what I said in more detail. Bottom line is, you need to give a list of pointers to your elements, may it be with "pointer-to-pointers to the base" or using a "vector of pointers to the base".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me see if I can explain the problem using couple of simple classes.

Let's say you have:

```
struct Foo
{
   char a;
};

struct Bar : Foo
{
   char b;
};
```

`sizeof(Foo)` is `1` and `sizeof(Bar)` is `2`.

And you create an array of `Bar` object using:

```
Bar* barPtr = new Bar[2];
```

The layout of memory that `barPtr` points to looks like:

```
Bar(0)  Bar(1)
|       |
v       v
+---+---+---+---+
| a | b | a | b |
+---+---+---+---+
```

If you pass that pointer to a function a `Foo*`, that function will interpret the memory as (since `sizeof(Foo) == 1`):

```
Foo(0)  
|   Foo(1)
|   |
v   v
+---+---+
| a | a |
+---+---+
```

As you can see, `Foo(1)` is not really a `Foo` object. It is really the `Bar` sub-object of `Bar(0)`. This can easily lead to undefined behavior. Depending on the kinds of data a base class and a derived class have, it could easily crash your program.

The key point is that a pointer that points to an array of derived class objects cannot be treated as a pointer that points to an array of base class objects.

Answer (score 2):

Very good explanation from R Sahu. It clearly describes why your code isn't working and deserves to be accepted.

So what can you do instead?

As far as I understand you want to pass all your CTree01 to a function in one call and have that function iterate all your CTree01s.

The only way I know is to make the container (i.e. array, vector) holding the base class pointers instead of CTree01.

Something like this:

```
class A
{
public:
    A() { cout << "A constructor" << endl;}
    virtual ~A() { cout << "A destructor" << endl;}
    void hello() { cout << "Hello from A" << endl;}
};

class B : public A
{
public:
    B() { cout << "B constructor" << endl;}
    ~B() override { cout << "B destructor" << endl;}
};

void f(array<A*,2>& t)
{
    for(auto e : t)
    {
        e->hello();
    }
}

int main()
{
    array<A*,2> z;   // Base class pointer array
    z[0]=new B;      // but it can still hold pointers to B
    z[1]=new B;
    f(z);
    delete z[0];
    delete z[1];
    return 0;
}
```

or using vector instead of array

```
class A
{
public:
    A() { cout << "A constructor" << endl;}
    virtual ~A() { cout << "A destructor" << endl;}
    void hello() { cout << "Hello from A" << endl;}
};

class B : public A
{
public:
    B() { cout << "B constructor" << endl;}
    ~B() override { cout << "B destructor" << endl;}
};

void f(vector<A*>& t)
{
    for(auto e : t)
    {
        e->hello();
    }
}

int main()
{
    vector<A*> z;
    z.push_back(new B);
    z.push_back(new B);
    f(z);
    delete z[0];
    delete z[1];
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ok i understand it now, it's working! Thanks for writing down this solution